# regex for joomla 2.5 language file

Tags: regex, eclipse, notepad++

I have a joomla 1.7 language file that looks like this

```
LUOGO NASCITA="Luogo di nascita:"
NAZIONE="Nazione:"
```

And i need to change it to

```
LUOGO_NASCITA="Luogo di nascita:"
NAZIONE="Nazione:"
```

Since 2.5 joomla decided to not allow space in the key name ( http://docs.joomla.org/Specification_of_language_files ), i'm searching for [A-Z] [A-Z] with Eclipse or Notepad++.

How can I change the space " " with the underscore "_" without removing the letter on the left and on the right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use capturing groups for the regex:

```
/([A-Z])\s([A-Z])/g
```

and replace with

```
$1_$2
```

But beware that this will also remove any such strings inside your language itself.

Comment: w00t, i used find ([A-Z0-9])\s([A-Z0-9]) and replace with \1_\2 in notepad++ worked

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure how Notepad++ uses backtraces. Some programs do `$`, some do `\ `. Glad I could help.